# how do I create android app using wordpress database?

Tags: android, android-studio, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had completed my website in wordpress,so can I use my wordpress database to connect android app? how? give me perfect references.

Comment: Search on _Google_

Comment: search Google for "client-server communication in android"

Comment: I tried but could not find best reference, that's why I posted this question. @MD

Comment: ok then [check this How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I give you a perfect reason for why you will not receive an answer to this question: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: I would like to learn how to ask but before that you should learn how to give answers for beginners. @MD

Comment: I accept it sir. Thank you for your answer but look, you search on google and give me reference if you are good on this. @MD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFbwW4ERUN0

or check Prabeesh RK android MySQL playlist in youtube to learn more..

only difference will be instead of creating a new database you will already have one.
just ensure whatever tables you create has the table_prefix that matches your $table_prefix in wp-config.php file

Hope this helps

Take care and Happy coding